# Significato di "da buon patto" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Fosforo* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Mi misi al lavoro, pochissimo persuaso, persuaso invece che il Commendatore, e magari il Kerrn medesimo, avessero soggiaciuto al fascino **da buon patto** dei nomi e dei luoghi comuni; infatti il fosforo ha un nome molto bello (vuol dire «portatore di luce»), è fosforescente, c’è nel cervello, c’è anche nei pesci, e *perciò* mangiare pesci rende intelligenti; senza fosforo le piante non crescono; fosfatina Falières, glicerofosfati per i bambini anemici di cento anni fa; c’è anche nelle capocchie dei fiammiferi, e le ragazze disperate per amore le mangiavano per suicidarsi; c’è nei fuochi fatui, putride fiamme innanzi al passegger.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "da buon patto" che appare nel testo. Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/patto) ho trovato

> *comprare a buon p., a buoni p.*, a condizioni vantaggiose.

E anche sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI12/00000865.jpg) si legge

> – *A, da buon patto* (con valore aggett.): che ha un prezzo o comporta una spesa relativamente bassa, conveniente.
>
> [...]
>     – Con valore avverb.: a un prezzo conveniente, relativamente basso; con poca spesa.

E anche:

> – *A buon patto*: molto facilmente.
> [...]
>     – *A buon patto* (con valore aggett.): di poco conto.

Tuttavia, non mi sembra che tutte queste accezioni abbiano senso nel contesto del passaggio sopra citato. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "da buon patto" nel testo?

Comment: Secondo me equivale a "a buon mercato"

Comment: Sì, @RiccardoDeContardi, le definizioni dei dizionari sembrano indicare che si tratta di un'espressione equivalente a "a buon mercato". Ma cosa significherebbe "fascino a buon mercato"?

Comment: Come dire "da poco", "da quattro soldi", "che non vale niente"

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi:  Quindi, il senso sarebbe che si lasciavano facilmente affascinare da qualcosa che non ne valeva la pena?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Potresti scriverlo come risposta, per favore?